# Deletar linha de uma lista em C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho uma lista conforme descrito abaixo
Gostaria de  deletar uma linha da lista `mylistnova1` conforme condição for verdadeira.
Tento fazer como descrito abaixo mas gera erro! Poderiam por favor me ajudar?
Abs.
       public  DataTable TrataConsulta(DataTable tabela )
        {

```
        NewDb openDb3 = new NewDb();
        DataTable Carga01 = tabela.Copy();
        DataTable Carga02 = tabela.Copy();
        //Carrega  DataTablepara uma lista
        var mylist = tabela.AsEnumerable().ToList();
         var mylistnova = tabela.AsEnumerable().ToList();
          var mylistnova1 = tabela.AsEnumerable().ToList();

    //    var mylist1 = ResultadoNovo.AsEnumerable().ToList();
        var mylist3 = Carga02.AsEnumerable().ToList();

           using (MySqlConnection db = openDb3.AbrirConexaoMySql())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        db.Open();



        foreach (var Item in mylist3)
        {

            string renavamrecebe = Convert.ToString(Item.ItemArray[1]);
        }


        foreach (var item02 in mylist)
         {

         string renavanRecebido = item02.ItemArray[01].ToString();
         string ComparaceuNoCartorio = item02.ItemArray[20].ToString();
         Datarecebe = item02.ItemArray[20].ToString();
                 foreach (var item03 in mylistnova1)
                 {
                      string tipocomptaVendaRecebe = Convert.ToString(item03.ItemArray[20]);
                Datarecebe1 = Convert.ToString(item03.ItemArray[15]);

                        renavamContagem = Convert.ToInt32((MamData.MySql.DUT.SelectQuantidadeRenavan(db, renavanRecebido, Datarecebe1)));




                        if (renavamContagem > 1)
                        {

                            if (renavanRecebido == Convert.ToString(item03.ItemArray[1]) && tipocomptaVendaRecebe == "C")
                            {

                                // Marco as linhas a serem deletadas
                                mylistnova1.RemoveAll(x => x == item03.ItemArray[1]); 

                            }


                        }




                 }
         }
        }



                    catch
                    {

                    }
                    db.Close();
                }
           DataTable ResultadoNovo = mylistnova1.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
           return (ResultadoNovo);
    }


    public DataTable ConvertToDataTable<T>(IList<T> data)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties =
           TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
        foreach (T item in data)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
                row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return table;

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Qual erro está gerando e em qual linha?

Comment: Na verdade não dá nenhum erro mas em compensação, não deleta a linha da lista caso seja verdadeira...

Comment: tenta modificar a linha `mylistnova1.RemoveAll(item04 => item04 == item04.ItemArray[1]);` para `mylistnova1.RemoveAll(x => x == item04.ItemArray[1]);` e vê se dá certo

Comment: Coloca a declaração das duas listas e se ela forem de objetos coloca os objetos na pergunta. Não é difícil excluir não, coloca as declarações que fica mais fácil de ver o problema

Comment: Atualizei Carlos o código para completo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pelo que entendi você quer fazer uma validação no item da lista `mylistnova1` e caso seja validado então você o exclui da lista.

Nesse caso você não pode excluir de uma lista que está no loop, por exemplo:

**(ISSO DA ERRO)**

```
foreach (var item in lista)
{
    lista.Remove(item);
}
```

> {"Coleção foi modificada; talvez a operação de enumeração não seja
>   executada."}

Nesse caso você pode usar o `.ToList()` para ele fazer uma cópia em memoria da lista e rodar a copia, liberando a lista original para poder excluir.

Aqui ele apaga a `lista` toda:

```
foreach (var item in lista.ToList())
{
     lista.Remove(item);
}
```

No seu caso eu faria assim:

```
foreach (var item03 in mylistnova1.ToList())
                 {
                      string tipocomptaVendaRecebe = Convert.ToString(item03.ItemArray[20]);
                Datarecebe1 = Convert.ToString(item03.ItemArray[15]);

                        renavamContagem = Convert.ToInt32((MamData.MySql.DUT.SelectQuantidadeRenavan(db, renavanRecebido, Datarecebe1)));




                        if (renavamContagem > 1)
                        {

                            if (renavanRecebido == Convert.ToString(item03.ItemArray[1]) && tipocomptaVendaRecebe == "C")
                            {

                                // Marco as linhas a serem deletadas
                                mylistnova1.Remove(item03); 

                            }


                        }




                 }
```

**ATUALIZANDO**

Como você falou de lentidão em consulta então acredito que você está lidando com muitos dados, verifica se o `.ToList()` vai manter a performance desejada.

Comment: Perfeito Ricardo!!! Deu certíssimo!!! Muito obrigado.... Como posso validar vc mesmo?

Comment: Tem um "V" abaixo de onde você vota pra cima ou pra baixo do lado esquerdo do inicio da resposta. Clica nesse V. Que bom que deu certo.

Answer (score 2):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
mylistnova1.Remove(mylistnova1.Single(item04 => item04.propriedade == comparador));
```

Comment: Não causou efeito algum ...isto é, nao deu erro e tambem nao deletou a linha...Uma pergunta...Andre,  a variavel  item4 o que seria?pois no foreach é item03 !!!Existe deleção de linha em lista ou terei que converter para um DataTable?

Comment: Joelias, você não sabe o que é uma variável do seu código? Você mesmo colocou ela na pergunta.

Comment: Dei um Update completo no codigo

Comment: O item04 é um iterador que existe tendo da estrutura da consulta LINQ. Essa variável vai se transmutar em cada item da lista durante a busca, até que a condição seja encontrada. Eu atualizei a resposta, pois havia um erro de sintaxe. Também mudei o nome das variaveis pra facilitar a compreensão. Não precisa converter pra datatable não, listas são mutáveis por natureza =)

Comment: Me desculpe os campos redundantes mas é que eu estava testando com DataTables e até funcionou mas a consulta ficou muito lenta.